# For each IPA phone, are there animations or videos that depict the vocal tract during articulation?

Tags: phonetics, ipa, resource-request, online-resources, phones

**(TL;DR)** For each IPA phone, are there animations, ams, pictures or videos that depict exactly and precisely the location of your articulators (eg: your tongue), needed to articulate that letter?

---

**Optional Reading:**  Though replete with typos, [this website](http://karlita2012pedagogiaingles.blogspot.com/2012_02_01_archive.html) includes helpful pictures and simple explanations.

I  use charts featuring audio (clips of) pronunciations as [such](http://web.uvic.ca/ling/resources/ipa/charts/IPAlab/IPAlab.htm). However, though based on words on anatomy, IPA's terminology is less precise than a diagram. Listening to the audio clips do not aid me to pinpoint where to place my articulators; I must experiment and guess, inefficiently and futilely. For example, I still don't know where the tongue must be situated to pronounce the alveolar trill `r`. [Anecdotes](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/3216) conflict and haven't helped me.

[This Quora answer](http://qr.ae/RNqGaF) affirms the utility in 'familiarity with the anatomy', for mastering the IPA.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I should think that there are a number of sources.

- For example, the [University of Sheffield](https://learnipa.group.shef.ac.uk/IPAChart/index.html) offers videos for every IPA sound.
- If the sounds of English, Spanish and German are enough for you, the [University of Iowa](http://soundsofspeech.uiowa.edu/) has an animated app/web-app with videos.

Edit: I think [reddit.com/r/ipa](https://www.reddit.com/r/ipa) is also noteworthy, as most new apps and websites about the topic come up there at some point.

Comment: Just adding on here, UBC's eNunciate has cool (and spooky) ultrasound overlays of various consonants and vowels: 

http://enunciate.arts.ubc.ca/linguistics/the-ipa-chart/consonants-pulmonic/

http://enunciate.arts.ubc.ca/linguistics/the-ipa-chart/vowels/

Comment: The Sheffield website is unaccessible now. And the Iowa site is unavailable for non-Flash users.

Comment: I've updated the Sheffield link - now it works.

Answer (score 4):

[Seeing Speech](http://www.seeingspeech.ac.uk/) is a remarkable site that has MRI, UTI and animations for most IPA sounds.