# How do you articulate the uvular trill, when you can already articulate the uvular fricative?

Tags: phonetics, french, ipa

`Key Assumptions:` 
 1. My uncle speaks only [General American](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_American_English_regional_phonology#General_American) English
(so he cannot resort to other languages' phonetic inventories).

2. Whenever he tries to phonate the uvular trill [[ʀ]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uvular_trill), he fails and instead **phonates perfectly** the voiced uvular fricative [[ʁ]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiced_uvular_fricative) (so about which I am not asking here).
3. Having perpetually rewatched [this animation of the vocal tract for [ʀ]](http://ipa.group.shef.ac.uk/dialog_main.php?num=17&type=consonants) (see [this](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/12874/5306)), he knows perfectly the physical corporeal [features](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uvular_trill#Features) of [ʀ], but which still fail to aid him to phonate [ʀ].
   So please do not repeat or explain with physical features.
4. The only solution appears to be [this method](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/14835/5306) from which I learned to phonate the alveolar trill, which cleverly exploits and combines phones in English to mimic another phone.
5. > [[Source:]](http://forum.unilang.org/viewtopic.php?t=36017#p774735) My trick is say /a/. Then /g/. Then "gra". Those two sounds are made at the same position of the tongue and uvular.

`Problem:` Sadly, 5 did not aid my uncle.
So what other (combinations of) phones in English should be tried to phonate [ʀ]?